# Most Active Contributors Monthly Report - April 2019

Tags: discussion, most-active-contributors, announcement

## Welcome to the 19th edition of the monthly Ask Different Most Active Contributors Report.

Please don't hesitate to share your valuable feedback in the comments.

[image: TITLE: REPORT TITLE]

### Report for April 2019

This report includes the following sections:

1. Overall Most Active Contributors Award
2. Monthly Reputation Leader Board
3. Most Active Editors Award
4. Most Active Voters Award
5. Most Active Close Vote Reviewers
6. Most Active First Post Reviewers
7. Most Active Late Answer Reviewers
8. Most Active Low-Quality Post Reviewers
9. Most Active Reopen Post Reviewers
10. Most Suggested Edits Reviewed Award
11. Highest Voted Questions Award
12. Highest Voted Answers Award
13. Most Viewed Questions Award
14. Ranked 1st Summary List
15. Moderators Activity Summary

---

[image: TITLE: OVERALL MOST ACIVE CONTRIBUTORS AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                  SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   Nimesh Neema              500
2   Allan                     210
3   bmike                     200
4   Glorfindel                160
5   nohillside, slm           150
```

**Note:** This is an overall ranking based on all activities. Maximum possible score = 1,150.

---

[image: TITLE: MONTHLY REPUTATION LEADER BOARD]

[image]

A total of 1,773 users earned reputation during the month. You can view the full list [here](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/118/month/apple/2019-04-02).<sup>1</sup>

---

[image: TITLE: MOST ACTIVE EDITORS AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                  EDITS
---------------------------------------
1   Nimesh Neema              261
2   bmike                      81
3   slm                        61
4   IconDaemon                 56
5   nohillside                 43
```

A big thank you to all 22 users who edited questions or answers this month!

---

[image: TITLE: MOST ACTIVE VOTERS AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                  VOTES
---------------------------------------
1   PeterJ                  1,346
2   Nimesh Neema              499
3   slm                       390
4   user97627                 384
5   bmike                     329
```

A big thank you to all 67 users who voted on questions or answers this month!<sup>2</sup>

---

[image: ![TITLE: MOST ACTIVE CLOSE VOTE REVIEWERS]

```
#   WINNER                  SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   nohillside                 66
2   Nimesh Neema               37
3   Allan                      23
4   Glorfindel                 18
5   fsb                        14
```

A big thank you to all 17 users who reviewed Close Votes this month!

---

[image: TITLE: MOST ACTIVE FIRST POST REVIEWERS]

```
#   WINNER                  SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   Nimesh Neema              400
2   Glorfindel                124
3   bmike                     109
4   fsb                       106
5   Monomeeth                  97
```

A big thank you to all 27 users who reviewed First Posts this month!

---

[image: ![TITLE: MOST ACTIVE LATE ANSWERS REVIEWERS]

```
#   WINNER                  SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   Nimesh Neema               58
2   Glorfindel                 33
3   Allan                      19
4   Tetsujin                   15
5   bmike, fsb                 14
```

A big thank you to all 16 users who reviewed Late Answers this month!

---

[image: ![TITLE: MOST ACTIVE LOW-QUALITY POST REVIEWERS]

```
#   WINNER                  SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   Nimesh Neema               20
2   Allan                      15
3   Glorfindel                 13
4   nohillside                 12
5   Tetsujin                    9
```

A big thank you to all 15 users who reviewed Low-Quality Posts this month!

---

[image: ![TITLE: MOST ACTIVE REOPEN POST REVIEWERS]

```
#   WINNER                  SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   Nimesh Neema               13
2   nohillside                 11
3   Allan                       7
4   Glorfindel                  6
5   bmike, Tetsujin             5
```

A big thank you to all 12 users who reviewed Reopen Votes this month!

---

[image: ![TITLE: MOST ACTIVE SUGGESTED EDIT REVIEWERS]

```
#   WINNER                  SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   Nimesh Neema               60
2   Allan                      48
3   nohillside                 41
4   bmike                      40
5   Glorfindel                 31
```

A big thank you to all 46 users who reviewed Suggested Edits this month!

---

[image: TITLE: HIGHEST VOTED QUESTION AWARD]

1. [I Accidentally Deleted a Stock Terminal Theme](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/356048/i-accidentally-deleted-a-stock-terminal-theme)

   - Posted by: joe_04_04
   - Votes: **26**
2. [My ex-girlfriend uses my Apple ID to log in to her iPad. Do I have to give her my Apple ID password to reset it?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/355277/my-ex-girlfriend-uses-my-apple-id-to-log-in-to-her-ipad-do-i-have-to-give-her-m)

   - Posted by: AGamePlayer
   - Votes: **25**
3. [Is it possible to run Internet Explorer on OS X El Capitan?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/356007/is-it-possible-to-run-internet-explorer-on-os-x-el-capitan)

   - Posted by: Sara Pruneddu
   - Votes: **16**
4. [How to find all the available tools in mac terminal?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/356886/how-to-find-all-the-available-tools-in-mac-terminal)

   - Posted by: Spear A1
   - Votes: **15**
5. [How to type a long/em dash '—'](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/356563/how-to-type-a-long-em-dash)

   - Posted by: Mig82
   - Votes: **14**

---

[image: TITLE: HIGHEST VOTED ANSWER AWARD]

1. [My ex-girlfriend uses my Apple ID to log in to her iPad. Do I have to give her my Apple ID password to reset it?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/355281/168832)

   - Posted by: Solar Mike
   - Votes: **71**
2. [I Accidentally Deleted a Stock Terminal Theme](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/356049/168832)

   - Posted by: joe_04_04
   - Votes: **38**
3. [How to type a long/em dash '—'](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/356566/168832)

   - Posted by: Tetsujin
   - Votes: **34**
4. [My ex-girlfriend uses my Apple ID to log in to her iPad. Do I have to give her my Apple ID password to reset it?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/355279/168832)

   - Posted by: Nimesh Neema
   - Votes: **32**
5. [Is it possible to run Internet Explorer on OS X El Capitan?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/356014/168832)

   - Posted by: Ryan McDonough
   - Votes: **27**

---

[image: TITLE: MOST VIEWED QUESTION AWARD]

1. [My ex-girlfriend uses my Apple ID to log in to her iPad. Do I have to give her my Apple ID password to reset it?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/355277/my-ex-girlfriend-uses-my-apple-id-to-log-in-to-her-ipad-do-i-have-to-give-her-m)

   - Posted by: AGamePlayer
   - Views: **13,669**
2. [App Store: “To update this app, you need to accept it on the Account page”](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/355973/app-store-to-update-this-app-you-need-to-accept-it-on-the-account-page)

   - Posted by: Simon Woodside
   - Views: **6,559**
3. [Is it possible to run Internet Explorer on OS X El Capitan?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/356007/is-it-possible-to-run-internet-explorer-on-os-x-el-capitan)

   - Posted by: Sara Pruneddu
   - Views: **3,803**
4. [Latest macOS Mojave update (10.14.4) and Mail.app Google accounts issue](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/355361/latest-macos-mojave-update-10-14-4-and-mail-app-google-accounts-issue)

   - Posted by: Peter Samokhin
   - Views: **3,323**
5. [I Accidentally Deleted a Stock Terminal Theme](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/356048/i-accidentally-deleted-a-stock-terminal-theme)

   - Posted by: joe_04_04
   - Views: **2,795**

---

[image: TITLE: RANKED 1st SUMMARY LIST]

**1.    Overall Most Active Contributors Award**

- [Nimesh Neema](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/279727/nimesh-neema)

**2.    Monthly Reputation Leader Board**

- [Nimesh Neema](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/279727/nimesh-neema)

**3.    Most Active Editors Award**

- [Nimesh Neema](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/279727/nimesh-neema)

**4.    Most Active Voters Award**

- [PeterJ](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/83841/peterj)

**5.    Most Active Close Vote Reviewers Award**

- [nohillside](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/9058/nohillside)

**6.    Most Active First Post Reviewers Award**

- [Nimesh Neema](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/279727/nimesh-neema)

**7.    Most Active Late Answer Reviewers Award**

- [Nimesh Neema](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/279727/nimesh-neema)

**8.    Most Active Low-Quality Post Reviewers Award**

- [Nimesh Neema](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/279727/nimesh-neema)

**9.    Most Active Reopen Post Reviewers Award**

- [Nimesh Neema](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/279727/nimesh-neema)

**10.   Most Active Suggested Edit Reviewers Award**

- [Nimesh Neema](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/279727/nimesh-neema)

**11.   Highest Voted Questions Award**

- [joe_04_04](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/165068/joe-04-04)

**12.   Highest Voted Answers Award**

- [Solar Mike](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/237687/solar-mike)

**13.   Most Viewed Questions Award**

- [AGamePlayer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/33489/agameplayer)

---

[image: TITLE: MODERATORS ACTIVITY SUMMARY]

In April our [Moderators](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) actioned **430 flags** with an average handling time of **13 minutes**. In summary, we also:

- deleted 405 comments
- deleted 259 posts
- closed 175 posts
- edited 229 posts
- created 76 posts
- created 513 comments

---

Please join me in thanking all contributors for volunteering their time to make this site so great. We appreciate the contributions made by all users, not just those listed in this report!

Keep up the great work! :)

---

<sup>**1.** Due to the possibility of profile changes over time, this link may not reflect the screenshot above.</sup>

<sup>**2.** Only users who have voted over 10 times in the period are counted in this metric.</sup>